# Deregister in Germany

Tags: germany, resident-permit, relocation

I've lived and worked in Germany for a couple of years, but recently I got an opportunity in another country out of the EU. I decided to pursue it and assess if it's for me; therefore, I didn't want to burn any bridges, so I haven't done my *abmeldung*/de-registeration yet. I moved approx. 4 months ago. Now that I'm certain that I'll be living in the new country for the foreseable future, I've decided to de-register myself in Germany and stop paying health insurance and rent.

My questions are:

1. How long does the de-register process take online considering the travel restrictions due to Covid?
2. Since I've not moved any money earned and taxed here in the new country to my German bank account, do I need to pay taxes in Germany?
3. Do I need to file for taxes in Germany?
4. What other things should I be aware of for de-registration and anything that follows?

Answer (score 0):

1. No idea, sorry.
2. Usually Germany has something that's called 'Doppelbesteuerungsabkommen'. Since you mentioned that you're still in the EU, this certainly exists for the country you moved to. Basically it means that if you have your main residency in another country AND the center of your life is in that country, you pay taxes in that country - exclusively.
3. No, not if (2) applies and you have no additional income out of Germany.
4. Again, no idea, sorry.

I'm planning to move to Bulgaria soon so I'd be quite interested to hear (1) and (2) myself.